# Как отправлять музыку чтобы она сохранялась с нужным названием через aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Я использую aiogram чтобы отправлять пользователю скачанную музыку, но если он ее сохраняет  она сохраняется как просто "audio", а не с нужным названием и расширением, использую метод reply_audio и передаю сам файл и title, как сделать чтобы музыка сохранялась с нужным названием?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```py
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["audio"])
async def test(message: types.Message):
    await message.audio.download(destination_file=f"{message.audio.file_name.split('.')[0]}.mp3")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['audio'])
async def save_audio(msg: types.Message):
    file_name = msg.audio.file_name
    await msg.audio.download(destination_file=f'download/audios/{file_name}')
    # имя файла сохраняется полностью (с любым кол-вом точек и других знаков)
```